# print("hello world", end=' ') causes syntax error

Tags: python

I have created a module that I use in another program.
The module prints some text, sleeps for a second, and then prints some more text (on the same line, and without any spaces).
I am running python 2.7, and `from __future__ import print_function` is the first line in the program that calls my module, but when I import my module, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\######\document.py", line 3
1, in <module>
    import mymodule
  File "C:\######\document.py", line 2
    print("hello world", end=' ')
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here's the code:

```
def run():
    print("hello world", end =' ')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(".", end =' ')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(".", end =' ')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

How can I fix this without importing `print_function` twice?

Comment: Have you imported `print_function` _before_ trying to use it?

Comment: Python 2.7 doesn't support `print` as a function unless you do `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: yes, it is the first import in my program

Comment: What happens on the previous line? Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually recreates the issue.

Comment: It should work if it's the first import. What's going on in `mymodule`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am running python 2.7, and have imported print_function in the program that calls my module

That doesn't work. You have to do the future statement *in this module*, not in the script or module that imports it.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) for details. But the short version is: The future statement changes the way your module is compiled, so Python has to be able to see it at module compilation time, not just at runtime. (That's also why it has to be the first non-comment/docstring line in the file.)

---

OK, so that explains how to fix it, but it doesn't explain why there's a problem unless you already know when module compilation happens.

Oversimplifying a bit: When you `import spam` (if it hasn't already been imported during this session), Python goes looking for an appropriate `spam.py` file. If it finds one, it then looks for a `spam.pyc` that's newer than `spam.py`. If so, it just executes that. If not, it compiles `spam.py` into `spam.pyc`, then executes it.

So, because future statements affect the way code is compiled, if Python wanted to let your future statements affect other modules that you imported, it would have to store a different version of `spam.pyc` for each possible combination of future statements—maybe `spam.pyc`, `spam+print_function.pyc`, `spam+division.pyc`, `spam+print_function+division.pyc`, etc.

---

Finally:

> How can I fix this without importing print_function twice?

You really can't. Well, you *can*, but you don't want to. The cleanest and simplest way I can imagine doing this is to write an [import hook](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) that overrides the usual mechanism for looking for and compiling `.pyc` files to ensure that everything you `import` is treated as if it had all of your future statements applied (possibly using something like the `spam+print_function.pyc` trick I semi-facetiously suggested above, to make sure you don't collide with normal cache `.pyc` files. (See the [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) docs for info on letting the modules inherit your future flags, or specifying a set of them explicitly.)

If that sounds really cool to you, learning about Python's import system is a lot of fun, but I would strongly suggest waiting until you upgrade to at least Python 3.4 before doing so, because it's changed a lot, and for the better; it's a lot easier to learn (especially since the whole thing is written in Python and thoroughly documented, instead of a mess of C code scattered around three different places), and a lot more flexible (so you usually don't have to duplicate half of what Python normally does for you, you can just replace the one part you want to change).

Comment: Does "at module compilation time" actually explain things well enough for a novice? I'm not sure it's clear, and I'm not sure how to make it clearer…

Comment: you mean module compilation is after/during runtime?

Comment: @RyanKrage: module compilation to bytecode usually takes place just once, on first import, after which the bytecode is cached in a `.pyc` file.

Comment: So obviously it _isn't_ clear enough; let me try to fix that.